# create-react-app error in nodejs docker environment

Tags: node.js, docker, create-react-app

Start to learn `react` as a beginner using docker environment. And sample app can't be created as expected.

Any tips to do it in docker env?

```
$ docker run -it -p 8080:80 -v $PWD:/app -w /app node:12-slim bash
root@d53fd4b95282:/app# npx create-react-app my-app
npx: installed 91 in 9.796s

Creating a new React app in /app/my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.21.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
â  react
â  @babel/plugin-syntax-numeric-separator@^7.7.4
â  source-map@^0.5.0
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning sha.js@2.4.11: Invalid bin entry for "sha.js" (in "sha.js").
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
...
error An unexpected error occurred: "EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../../../parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/app/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/.bin/parser'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/app/my-app/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd /app/my-app has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
```

Comment: I'd recommend not involving Docker in this process at all.  A typical create-react-app setup has almost no host dependencies (just Node) and Docker introduces a lot of unnecessary complications.  Build your application directly on your host; consider packaging it in Docker if that's useful for your deployment environment.

Comment: Thx, I will do it now, and I still want to get the answer to why and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error happened because you were mounting a host folder inside the container and yarn attempted to create a symlink file pointing from this mount into a target that resides inside the container.

What exactly happens in this case depends on the underlying host filesystem, but at least in your case it seems the host filesystem rejects the request to create the symlink, hence the "protocol error". In this particular case, the target `babel-parser.js` is probably in the yarn cache residing on the container somewhere inside `~/.cache/yarn/`

You could either try mounting the whole home folder instead of just app folder, or alternatively try installing with `yarn install --no-bin-links` might also work out.