# I'm having trouble creating docker react app

Tags: docker, sh

I'm trying to get create-react-app working on my Ubuntu wsl2 without having to install node, but rather using Docker. I have the following.

so I have this utility.docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  npm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: utility.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

utility.Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "npm" ]
```

I also have a shell script

```
docker-compose -f utility.docker-compose.yml run --rm npm "init" "react-app" "my-app"
```

This is under my directory \wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\username\Projects

I am able to install npm packages by modifying the shell script to something like "install" "axios". That works, but I haven't had luck trying to create a react app that.

I keep getting this error "sh: create-react-app: Permission denied" I tried changing the permissions and ownership but nothing works.

```
sh: create-react-app: Permission denied
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /app
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- create-react-app my-app
```

But when I try it on my Windows10, it works easily. Any ideas on how to fix this issue? I kinda don't like to keep moving my files from Windows 10 to my WSl2 Ubuntu instance.

I prefer using wsl2 cause when I make a change in react, I can see the changes reflect right away as opposed to on Windows 10 I have to rebuild the containers.

Comment: can you try and run this: `docker run --rm -ti -v $(pwd):/app --workdir "/app" node:18-alpine npm init react-app my-app` and let me know if it works?

Comment: @Mihai I ran the above command on my /home/username/Projects directory, but it gave me the same error message. Permission denied.

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash from your bind mount source `- .:/app`

Comment: @JulienB. It still didn't work with permission BS, BUT, I did went back to what Mihai suggested, and found another stackoverflow question and added this... docker run -it -p 8080:80 -v $PWD:/app -w /app node:12-slim bash... to my surprised it worked! It mirrored it back to my host directory as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up finding another stackoverflow question that worked for my situation. I added the command below is what worked for me.

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80 -v $PWD:/app -w /app node:12-slim bash
```

The link below is the solution that worked for me.

[create-react-app error in nodejs docker environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59787447/create-react-app-error-in-nodejs-docker-environment)